# CSS Counter-increment and counter-reset

Tags: html, css

Please can someone explain to me why I am getting '1' even though reset is not applied to the subsection counter.I mean should I not get 1.1, 1.2 ,1.3 instead of 1.1, 1.1,1.1 for all h2 tag under the same h1 tag?I am a beginner in learning CSS and it would help me a lot if any one could explain.Thanks in advance. The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    counter-reset: section;
}

h1 {
    counter-reset: section;
}

h1:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "Section " counter(section) ". ";
}

h2:before {
    counter-increment: subsection;
    content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> IE8 supports these properties only if a !DOCTYPE is specified.</p>

<h1>HTML tutorials</h1>
<h2>HTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>XHTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2>

<h1>Scripting tutorials</h1>
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<h2>VBScript</h2>

<h1>XML tutorials</h1>
<h2>XML</h2>
<h2>XSL</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

**Output:** [image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Instead of

```
h1 {
    counter-reset: section;
}
```

It will be

```
h1 {
    counter-reset: subsection;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I actually wanted to know what is happening when I write  h1{counter-reset:section }

Answer (score 0):

See this very good article on `counter-reset` property.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/counter-reset/

As it said, `h1` element is used to reset `h2` `counter-increment` when a new `h1` occurs in the code.

**Example :**

```
<h1>HTML tutorials</h1> // count 1 
<h2>HTML Tutorial</h2> // count 1.1 because you have one h1 above
<h2>XHTML Tutorial</h2> // count 1.2
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2> // count 1.3

<h1>Scripting tutorials</h1> // count 2 because of the new h1 tag
<h2>JavaScript</h2> // count 2.1 because of the reset after the new h1 appears
<h2>VBScript</h2> // count 2.2
```

So you have to use this code to make the reset works properly on `h2:before` counter :

```
h1 {
    counter-reset: subsection // which is the name of h2 counter-increment;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I actually wanted to know what is happening when I write  h1{counter-reset:section }

Comment: It doens't increment h1:before value because everytime it tries to increment it, you reset it.

Comment: Ok.But what is happening with the h2:before value?why is that one not incremented?The subsection counter is not being reset anywhere.

Comment: Yes it is reset with h1 selector. Did you read all my answer and the article I've provided ? It is explained here.

Comment: Yes I read them but somehow I am not able to understand. h1 selector is resetting the counter(section). counter(subsection) is not reset is all I can understand.If it is ok  with you can you please point me out the point that I am missing here.

Comment: `h1` selector is reset by the container around which is `body` If you put the same reset in `h1`, it will not work because it is **already** reset by `body`. 
`h1` selector reset `h2:before` counter increment, which name is subsection, see the example in my answer. I don't know how I can be clearer as that sorry :)